# Select returning empty query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select data where by `acc_id`

What I get in my localhost: `[]`

However, when I set a specific `acc_id` i get the correct row is there something in my syntax?

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

// Define database connection parameters
$hn      = 'localhost';
$un      = 'root';
$pwd     = '';
$db      = 'ringabell';
$cs      = 'utf8';

// Set up the PDO parameters
$dsn  = "mysql:host=" . $hn . ";port=3306;dbname=" . $db . ";charset=" . $cs;
$opt  = array(
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                   );
// Create a PDO instance (connect to the database)
$pdo  = new PDO($dsn, $un, $pwd, $opt);
$data = array();


// Attempt to query database table and retrieve data
try {   
        $acc_id = $pdo->prepare('SELECT acc_id FROM account_info');
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT p_fname, p_lname, p_condition FROM patient_info WHERE acc_id = "$acc_id"');
        $stmt->execute([$acc_id]);
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            // Assign each row of data to associative array
            $data[] = $row;
        }

  // Return data as JSON
  echo json_encode($data);
  }
 catch(PDOException $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: You forgot `$pdo->execute(...)`   read ( http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php )

Comment: @RaymondNijland he is using `query`,  not `prepare` .

Comment: So his acc_id column actually has a value of `:acc_id` to match on? That is so odd ;)

Comment: i don't think `pdo->execute is the problem()` because when I set the value of `acc_id` it returns the row correctly!

Comment: He should be using prepare annyhow because he is using `WHERE acc_id =":acc_id` in his query @Azuloo

Comment: Yess @Randall i can insert and everything but it doesn't select

Comment: @Azuloo I tried `prepare` it doesn't change anything

Comment: You are confusing a direct query, and placeholders, when manually changing out the placeholder with a id value in the direct query. The answer below by Azuloo shows the right way to do it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, he should, but my point was that in the code he posted above he doesn't need to use `execute` because he used `query` even if it's wrong in this case.

Comment: @Azuloo i know i missed indeed the fact he was using pdo->query()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to use the *prepared statement* but instead executing your query instantly. If you want to bind the value to your query use something like this:

```
$acc_id = // get the $acc_id value from somewhere you want
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT p_fname, p_lname, p_condition FROM patient_info WHERE acc_id = ?');
$stmt->execute([$acc_id]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
     // Assign each row of data to associative array
     $data[] = $row;
}
```

### Example with using a placeholder

Instead of executing your statement with the array of params, you could also use the `bindValue()` or the `bindParam()` method:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT p_fname, p_lname, p_condition FROM patient_info WHERE acc_id = :acc_id');
$stmt->bindValue(':acc_id', $acc_id);
$stmt->execute();
// everything else works as previous
```

The difference between these two methods is written in docs:

[`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php):

> Binds a value to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement.

[`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> Binds a PHP variable to a corresponding named or question mark placeholder in the SQL statement that was used to prepare the statement. Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

Comment: You could also add an example using placeholders method with execute. Just so he is clear why his use of `:acc_id` wasn't working.

Comment: i got this error `Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string`

Comment: @Randall  yes please

Comment: @Voula16 I have just updated my answer. If you're trying to use `json_encode` on the array of results you've got use, for exapmle, `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. The error is occurring because you are trying to convert the `Object` type to a `string` by using the `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` key earlier.

Comment: i'm it didn't work i tried both. I fixed `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` same error and the second and me `[]`

Comment: If you're still getting an empty array you better check the value you're binding to your query. I suppose it's not what you're expecting it to be.

Comment: but `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` still gets me the error  `Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string` the error occurs on `$stmt->execute([$acc_id]);`

Comment: @Voula16 Post me the entire code you've got after all the changes here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160852/select-returning-empty-query so I could help you.

Comment: Thank you sorry not enough reputation i will edit my post !

Comment: Of course you're getting the error. On this line `acc_id = "$acc_id"` you're inserting the variable **right into** the query string which is considered a **bad practice** because your code becomes completely open for SQL injections and after this you call `execute([$acc_id])` which expects you to have `:acc_id` placeholder in your query string. Just change it for the correct version I described above: `$pdo->prepare('SELECT p_fname, p_lname, p_condition FROM patient_info WHERE acc_id = :acc_id'); $stmt->bindValue(':acc_id', $acc_id); $stmt->execute();`

Comment: sorry for that but I still get an `empty array` ( the user is logged in with an `acc_id` common for all my tables i want the query to select the `acc_id` where it is signed in and give me the values) it works with I `insert`

Comment: @Voula16 If you didn't change your code the problem is here: `$acc_id = $pdo->prepare('SELECT acc_id FROM account_info');` - you made the prepare statement but didn't call the `execute()` method: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT acc_id FROM account_info'); $stmt->execute(); $acc_id = $stmt->fetchColumn();`. Also you should use `WHERE` if you have multiple users to get the `acc_id` of the user logging in.

Comment: I changed my code to `$pdo->prepare('SELECT p_fname, p_lname, p_condition FROM patient_info WHERE acc_id = :acc_id'); $stmt->bindValue(':acc_id', $acc_id); $stmt->execute();` and still `[]`

Comment: Yes, I got it, and I gave you the answer why is this happening: your `$acc_id` is **not** the result of this query - `SELECT acc_id FROM account_info` - because you did **not** executed this query but assigned the `PDOStatement` (the result of calling `prepare()` method) to the $acc_id variable. Please read more **carefully** what I wrote earlier.